# Match two chars except first and last

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to remove all `[` and `]` characters from a string, except the first and last instances.

I have looked for many solutions in SO, but can't solve this specific problem.

An input string can be in the following format:

`[foo:[foo, foo2], bar:[bar]]`

and I need it to be:

`[foo:foo, foo2, bar:bar]`

I tried this but the regex matches the char before `[`:

```
([^\[])(\[|\])
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have to do this with regular expressions only?

Comment: Youve got the string in hand, why not just remove all '[' and ']' in it, and then just rebuild the new string with a '[' prefix and a ']' postfix ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be regex only, but I need the optimal solution @thanopi57

Comment: I have to do it a lot.. maybe a regex could be faster, don't you think @RannLifshitz?

Comment: Define 'a lot'. Simplicity can go a longer way then optimization in many cases. Remember the KISS principle.

Comment: @RannLifshitz I'm aware of it, but a simple regex isn't better anyways? (thanks for the edit)

Comment: Your welcome. As you can see in your question - the regex is actually not that simple.... Your call, buddy.

Comment: @RannLifshitz sorry, I didn't see your comment. So yes, your comments I guess give the answer. Post your answer freely.

Comment: @thanopi57 : No worries buddy. Just being cynical. I do not want to make SO any harsher then it already is.

Comment: @RannLifshitz yeah.. i tried to avoid that, but I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: If you mean to avoid removing the `[` at the start and  and `]` at the end of the string, you may use `.replaceAll("(?<!^)\\[|\\](?!$)","")`. This is not flexible though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nothing like a regexp that looks like a mashup of random characters, right :D ?

Comment: @RannLifshitz Well, any code looks like a "random character mashup" to my wife. It is a matter of whether you are familiar with a technology or not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Well put, upvoted buddy.

Comment: @HansAraya does any answer address your question :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum things up, with a lot of thanks to [@thanopi57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6746785/thanopi57) who first implemented what I suggested in a comment : 
The brute force, no regex solution

```
String input = "[foo:[foo, foo2], bar:[bar]]";
String newInput = new StringJoiner("").add("[").
       add(input.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")).add("]").toString();
System.out.println(newInput);
```

Comment: @thanopi57 : any chance we can split the credit on this ? Post an answer and I'll upvote it or something.

Comment: Why not `input.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")` ? Even using stringBuilder to `stringBuilder.append('['); stringBuilder.append(input.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")); stringBuilder.append(']'); ` ?

Comment: This is just a temporary message to the Author: Please pay attention to the edits you suggest. A suggested edit should not contain spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this:

```
String str = "[foo:[foo, foo2], bar:[bar]]";
return str.replaceAll("(?<!])]", "").replaceAll("(?<=:)\\[", "");
```

`(?<!])]` is a negative lookbehind, `]` character NOT preceded by another `]`

`(?<=:)\[` is a positive lookbehind, `[` character preceded by `:`